# How to map arrays in the MapperProfile using typescript Automapper?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

## Typescript automapper createMap() for array returns empty {}

## How to map arrays in the MapperProfile?

**All Models**

```
export class ConfigurationModel extends BaseModel{
// set of members
}

export class GetConfigurationResponse extends CompositeBaseModel {
// same set of members
}
```

```
@Injectable()
export class CommonResponseModel<TModel extends BaseModel | BaseModel[]> {
  public message: string
  public data: TModel
  public error: any
}
```

This is the actual response of the API

```
@Injectable()
export class CompositeResponseModel<TModel extends CompositeBaseModel | CompositeBaseModel[]> {
  public message: string
  public data: TModel
  public error: any
}
```

**AutomapperProfile.ts**

```
createMap(
        mapper,
        CommonResponseModel<ConfigurationModel[]>,
        CompositeResponseModel<GetConfigurationResponse[]>,
        forMember(
          (d) => d.message,
          mapFrom((s) => s.message),
        ),
        forMember(
          (d) => d.message,
          mapFrom((s) => s.error),
        ),
        forMember(
          (d) => d.data,
          mapFrom((s) => s.data.map((x) => new GetConfigurationResponse(x. group, x.code, x. value, x._id, x.accountId, x.locationId, x.productId, x.roleId, x.effectiveFrom, x.effectiveTo))
          ),
        )
      )
```

**Controller.ts**

```
this._mapper.map(
      await this.configurationService.get(filter),
      CommonResponseModel<ConfigurationModel[]>,
      CompositeResponseModel<GetConfigurationResponse[]>,
    )
```

**ResponseInterceptor.ts**

```
prepareResponse(data: any, context: ExecutionContext): MIOResponse<T> {
    console.log(data.message)
    let computedStatus: any
    switch(data.message) {
      case MESSAGE_SUCCESS : computedStatus = HttpStatus.OK; break;
      case MESSAGE_CONFLICT: computedStatus = HttpStatus.CONFLICT; break;
      case MESSAGE_CREATED : computedStatus = HttpStatus.CREATED; break;
      case MESSAGE_UPDATED : computedStatus = HttpStatus.OK; break;
      case MESSAGE_DELETED : computedStatus = HttpStatus.OK; break;
      case MESSAGE_NOT_MODIFIED : computedStatus = HttpStatus.NOT_MODIFIED; break;
      default: computedStatus = HttpStatus.OK; break;
    }
    context.switchToHttp().getResponse().status(computedStatus)
    return {
      status: computedStatus,
      message: data.message,
      data: data.data,
      error: data.error,
    }
  }
```

**Result**

{
"status": 302,
"message": "FOUND",
"data": {},
"error": null
}